# Win32 ReleaseDC and DestroyWindow returning 0

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a single window created with the CS_OWNDC style for an engine I'm coding and it's showing properly, but when I'm closing the program and I call the ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC) the function returns 0 always (and according to MSDN it means it couldn't be released).
The DestroyWindow(hWnd) is also returning 0.

I am calling GetDC(hWnd) during the window creation.

What is weird is that I only get this error if I pass through the messaging function, even if it has nothing coded inside.

My main code is looking like this:

```
WindowManager windowManager;
HWND mainWindow = windowManager.Initialize("Title", "ClassName", 1024, 768, 32, WindowProc);

MSG msg;
while(true)
{
    if(PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        if(msg.message == WM_QUIT) { break; }
        else
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
}
windowManager.Clear(); //this calls ReleaseDC(hWnd, DC) and DestroyWindow(hWnd) among other release codes
```

What I don't understand is that if I comment the whole **while** loop, I don't get the release or destroy window errors.
Calling **GetLastError()** gives me a 0 too.
On MSDN it says the DestroyWindow must be called from the same thread, but I'm not coding any multi thread functions so I don't think that's the case.

What could be causing this?

Comment: I bet the window is already destroyed. The quit message is traditionally posted as part of window destruction.

Comment: You are correct, I just found out this... I was calling **PostQuitMessage(0);** when receiving the WM_DESTROY message instead of the WM_CLOSE, thus it was trying to destroy the window twice.
Sigh, and this error was haunting me for a couple of days now...